# Why do we worship Lord Hanuman on these weekdays?

Tags: belief, worship, hanuman

We generally associate a day for the worship of different gods, like Monday for Lord Shiva, Tuesday for Lord Hanuman. What is the reason that we worship Lord Hanuman on Tuesdays and Saturdays? What is the belief and benefits of worshipping him on the given days of the week?

Comment: It is according to astrology.

Comment: According to the Kurma-Purana, Hanumanji should be worshipped on SUNDAYS by chanting the Hanumat-Kavacha  to get victory and wealth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Partial Answer**

1. Kastabhanjan Hanuman Mandir ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanuman_temple,_Salangpur) is an old temple at Salangpur. According to this video: https://youtu.be/lK3nFGMQNnw when Hanumanji saved His devotees from the horrible effects of Sanidev who took the form of a woman to save himself from the anger of Bala-brahmachari Hanumanji. Hanumanji's idol worshipped there shows Sanidev as a female at His feet.An image is enclosed.

So Hanumanji saves His Devotees from Sanidev's rage seems an ancient idea.

2. Tulsidasji, a great preacher of Sri Hanuman Worship, describes Him as 'Mangala-Murati' in the Hanuman-Chalisa. This could be the basis of His being worshipped on Tuesdays(Mangala-vara).

According to the Kurma-Puran though, the day for Hanumanji's worship is Arka-vara ie Sunday. (Reference: Hanumat-Kavacham,Purohit-Darpan).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Hanumanji escaped the lord Shani from the Ravana's prison. Due to this, lord Shani pleased with Hanumanji and gave boon that whoever will worship lord Hanumanji then there will be no effect of lord Shani on him/her

Check [reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/the-story-of-lord-shani-ravana-hanuman/m-lite&ved=2ahUKEwi33MzCuYHiAhUBVH0KHbyHAlsQFjAOegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3CF4gBYjyynnmzkQxZ05SC&ampcf=1)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/601/what-is-the-concept-of-a-week-in-hinduism) and a comment posted [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/601/what-is-the-concept-of-a-week-in-hinduism#comment1346_621), states that

> Rahu and Ketu take up Tuesdays and Saturdays respectively

And as I remember (Please correct me if I am wrong) there was an incident of HanumanJi with Rahu, when HanumanJi tried to eat the Sun (I don't have the exact references for this).

So it could be linked to that.

EDIT:
I found the correct answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/584/15734).

Comment: Please write in brief about the story and then give the reference

Comment: @V.Aggarwal ,Actually what, Hanumanji escaped the lord Shani from the Ravana prisons, Due to this lord Shani pleased with Hanumanji and they have given the blessing that whoever will workship of the lord Hanumanji than there will be no effect of lord Shani on him/her

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha so according to you we now know why we worship lord hanuman on saturdays because he helped lord shani to escape from ravana's prison

Comment: do you have any references of this story in any book or is it just a folklore