# In North-East India, in the Shakta tradition, what days of the week is the fast for the Devi-bhaktas?

Tags: devi, shakti, shaktism, fasting, nava-durga

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate of this question : [Why each day of the week is dedicated to a particular god?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/580/why-each-day-of-the-week-is-dedicated-to-a-particular-god)

Because I'm asking the vrat-din of specific Shakta tradition in specific region of India (North-East), like Bengal and surrounding.
If it's considered duplicate, no problem, please delete.

Ok. So I understand the Hindu day-of-the-week fasts vary by state.
Just wondering what is the generally accepted day each week, in NE India, that Shakta people and Devi-bhaktas would keep the vrat.
I've read different things online, some say Tuesday, others say Friday or Saturday.

On a side note, I'm also wondering if all four annual Navaratri are celebrated in NE India?
I know Chaitra and Sharadiya are, clearly (Durga Puja, Basanti Puja, etc)

Are Magha Gupta Navaratri and Ashadha Gupta Navaratri also observed there?

During the four Navaratri, the fasting is all nine days if possible, from what I was taught.

Thx
(Plz feel free to edit my tags if I put those incorrectly)

Comment: For devi Gauri Monday fasts are prescribed as per Shiv puran, for Mangal chandi it's Tuesdays, other than that Fridays are considered auspicious for her puja as per Lokachar. Thou for Kali it's mainly Saturdays and Tuesdays. Thursdays for Laxmi in NE. Thou, tithis are dedicated for her worship such as Ashtami, Chaturdashi. Devi had promised that those who worship on Chaturdashi, she will bless them with opulence. Regarding the rest two Navaratri of Ashad and Magh, these are exclusively for Tantrics and those initiated in devi upasana. Thus, no information is released about both in general.

Comment: @Chamundadas Thx ! That is helpful, I appreciate you taking the time to type out this comment. Friday & Saturday vrat for Kali/Durga is what I heard most for Shakti-upasak. I observe the four Navratri w/ NavDurga/MahaVidya aradhana, though not formally an (initiated) Tantrika. Thx again

Comment: No don't thank me, it's all her mere will. I was just an instrumental person to carry out that. Yeah, as per Shastras Mahakali is worshipped on Saturday. And it's glad that you do 4 Navaratris as Bhakti sarvopari. May bhagwati Paramba Kali guide you and give you a guru in whichever kula you are interested in.